# Index row size 2976 exceeds btree version in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-14

We have seen some of the indexes are getting failing with below error.

```
ERROR: index row size 2976 exceeds byte version 4 maximum 2704 for index "idx1" HINT: Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed. Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

Index : Create index idx1 on table1 using btree(upper(col1));

Table column length: 4000 pg_column_size for that column: 2931
```

Can you please suggest how to fix this issue

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with. Stack Overflow can help you troubleshoot existing code, not write it for you. To learn more about how the community can help you, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error suggests that the indexed column col1 has values that are too large to be indexed directly. Since your column has a length of 4000, and the maximum size for the indexed column is 2704 bytes, you're exceeding this limit.

**Solutions:**

**Use a Hash Index:**

Instead of indexing the column directly, you can create an index on a hashed version of the column. This significantly reduces the size of the indexed data.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 USING btree (md5(upper(col1)));
```

**Use Text Pattern Ops:**

If your queries mostly involve LIKE or ILIKE queries, consider using text pattern ops.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 USING btree (upper(col1) text_pattern_ops);
```

**Truncate Data Before Indexing:**

If the data permits, consider indexing only a portion of the column.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 USING btree (left(upper(col1), 255));
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, We are looking to add gin index on this.